# unknown block type dns_config

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

i am getting error "Blocks of type "dns_config" are not expected here" in my terraform
main.tf file. Here is my code.
I am trying this in GCP
This code is breaking at dns_config section.

```
provider google {
  project       = var.project
  region        = var.region
  version       = "4.22.0"
  credentials   = var.credentials
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name               = "${var.service-name}-${lower(var.site-id)}"
  location           = var.region
  node_locations     = [var.zone]
  network            = var.vpc-id
  subnetwork         = var.subnet-id
  enable_autopilot   = true
  initial_node_count = var.initial-node-count

  dns_config {
    cluster_dns = "CLOUD_DNS"
    cluster_dns_domain = "cluster.qg${var.site-id}stream"
    cluster_dns_scope = "CLUSTER_SCOPE"
  }

  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name  = var.subnet-pod-ip-range-name
    services_secondary_range_name = var.subnet-service-ip-range-name
  }

  dynamic "release_channel" {
    for_each = var.release-channel != null ? [{ channel : var.release-channel }] : []

    content {
      channel = var.release-channel
    }
  }

  logging_service    = var.logging_service
  monitoring_service = var.monitoring_service
}

terraform {
  backend "pg" {}
}
```

Comment: I cannot find any information about a `testcluster` resource for any provider. Is the config in the question accurate?

Comment: Thank you matt for your message, it was typo. I have corrected it.
But issue comes at dns_config